# Performance - custom php block or views to use in panels

Tags: views, 6, nodes, panels, performance

I use panels to display block with node title on a custom position. My question is about performance - what is faster - to use following php code inside block

```
<?php
$node = menu_get_object(); print $node->title;
?>
```

or to use use views to get title of current node.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't worry about performance of little things like this.

You also don't need to resort to Views to get this information.

If you are using the **Node template** page from Page Manager, then you can

- edit the page
- select the variant
- edit the content
- click the gear on the panel you want to **Add Content**
- click the **Node** tab
- click **Node Title**

This will then be a normal panel pane that you can place as you need it.  This is one trick to get node content above the page title on complicated layouts.

Comment: Thank you, I know about this solution but that doe's not do the trick for me - it is rendered without h1 tags and "title" displays above no matter what.